# Why does truffle require 4 authorizations for 1 contract + 1 migration?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

Ok looking at this I see the Migrations.sol is setup by truffle to help you migrate versions of your contract?

I'm still getting prompted to unlock my wallet 2x per contract (2x per migration, 2x for my contract).

Why 2x instead of 1x?

```
truffle compile && truffle migrate --network=kovan
Using network 'kovan'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0x5ca98daea12403079262477b929880c92db79f652fa575d248ca1c9f3699f69b
  Migrations: 0x8f6f3b66cc52c15b4ab02ada34a3db222ce87d70
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xc0651e0c972162a555ff98c93251756ec96c135cfcd500faaddaeb0aec213a7b
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying IdleMiner...
  ... 0x36d241c8a51582381e769bc09e0e85bcf34ca8248e58109eebd5d5481732c06a
  IdleMiner: 0x7ba6f6878809a672e835354a95bf376ac51c210a
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xfa1fd8d7fc5c863fa6bfd628358c8d9a6e7f087a85b9debe52542a00889e8a2a
Saving artifacts...
```

Answer (score 4):

Migrations is used by truffle to remember which step in the process completed successfully. 
See [What are truffle migrations?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-are-truffle-migrations)

You have 4 authorization requests, because you have 4 transactions:

1. Deploy Migrations contract
2. update the current step in the deployed Migrations instance
3. Deploy your contract
4. update the current step in the deployed Migrations instance