# what is the role of Migrations.sol contract in truffle project?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I have started working with truffle since 4 months and I don't give importance to Migrations.sol, I thought it's just a "get started" contract. 
But when I removed it caused a problem. 
can anyone explains the role of this contract?

Comment: this is a good reason I am not using `truffle` , it pollutes my testing environment, debug logs, and also spends unnecessary money on deployment. Not everybody can make a perfect product, it takes discipline and customer oriented mentality to be the first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Migrations` contract keeps track of which migrations were done on the current network.

Inside the migrations folder, you'll see a file called `1_initial_migration.js` The `1` in the filename is the reference number of a migration.

Once you've created a couple of contracts, and want to deploy them using `truffle migrate`, you can create another migration file called `2_name_of_migration.js`. Once the migration is done, Truffle will store that `2` reference number in the `Migrations` contract

Comment: but in prod it will  consume gas that I'm not supposed to pay it.

Comment: Yeah, correct. I'm not a fan of this system because of that

Comment: So why this is necessary, can you turn it off?

Answer (score 7):

Good Answer from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-are-truffle-migrations):

> The Migrations contract stores (in last_completed_migration) a number that corresponds to the last applied "migration" script, found in the migrations folder. Deploying this Migrations contract is always the first such step anyway. The numbering convention is x_script_name.js, with x starting at 1. Your real-meat contracts would typically come in scripts starting at 2_....
>
> So, as this Migrations contract stores the number of the last
>   deployment script applied, Truffle will not run those scripts again.
>   On the other hand, in the future, your app may need to have a
>   modified, or new, contract deployed. For that to happen, you create a
>   new script with an increased number that describes the steps that need
>   to take place. Then, again, after they have run once, they will not
>   run again.