# Deploying Migrations.sol file in mainnet

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I've seen some tutorials about deploying a smart contract to mainnet using Truffle.

In those tutorials they are also deploying Migrations.sol contract to mainnet.

What is the purpose of doing that? I think it's not necessary to deploy Migrations.sol contract to mainnet. Isn't it just for development purposes? What would happen if I don't deploy that contract to mainnet?

Comment: It is used for development purposes https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56411/what-is-the-role-of-migrations-sol-contract-in-truffle-project.