# What's the point of Truffle Migrations?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I've been reading a few articles and StackExchange posts (e.g. [What are truffle migrations?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-are-truffle-migrations)) about Truffle Migrations, but I still don't get it: why do we need them?

It seems they do only one thing (correct me if I'm wrong): store a number in a contract so we know which (version of) the contracts we already deployed.

Thing is, deploying a contract and making transactions **isn't cheap**: it means spending Ether and also increasing the size of the blockchain forever. It seems like a **heavy cost** for just storing an integer we could store **locally** for example.

So I'm wondering: did I miss other features offered by Truffle migrations? Why don't we store that information locally (or somewhere else)?

Comment: That are questions you should make to Truffle developers. I'd use Truffle only for development/testing cycle and for production I'd use my own scripts.