# Why does deploying a contract causes two transactions?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, ganache, vyper

I am new to Ethereum, learning about smart contracts.
I have a simple hello world contract.

```
# @version ^0.3.7

@external
@pure
def hola() -> String[5]:
    return "hola!"
```

Currently, I'm doing experiments to find out how much wei it costs to deploy a contract.

When I deploy my contract to Ganache UI, its log shows two transactions, with two separate gas fees.

**Question: I only expect one transaction.  Why are there two?**

---

Ganache Log:

```
[5:23:15 PM]   Transaction: 0x1fd75f313be224fb941c37d62548c0e68cba47ce61f99a2c5d2ff0db646418d2
[5:23:15 PM]   Contract created: 0x56f36098ae392a06540387ffa56ea43624e806e7
[5:23:15 PM]   Gas usage: 201627
[5:23:15 PM]   Block Number: 6
[5:23:15 PM]   Block Time: Tue Feb 07 2023 17:23:15 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
[5:23:15 PM] eth_getTransactionReceipt[5:23:15 PM] eth_getBlockByNumber
[5:23:15 PM] eth_getCode[5:23:15 PM] eth_getBlockByNumber
[5:23:15 PM] eth_getBlockByNumber[5:23:15 PM] eth_estimateGas
[5:23:15 PM] eth_getBlockByNumber[5:23:15 PM] eth_gasPrice
[5:23:15 PM] eth_sendTransaction
[5:23:15 PM]   Transaction: 0xeb19faa88d021e2e94e2a89a5718b64793e8e47936bff2dc9008bb22c298f297
[5:23:15 PM]   Gas usage: 42513
[5:23:15 PM]   Block Number: 7
[5:23:15 PM]   Block Time: Tue Feb 07 2023 17:23:15 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
```

Truffle config:

```
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
    }
```

Test/Deploy code:

```
const Hello = artifacts.require("Hello");
contract("Hello Only", () => {
  it("...should deploy", async () => {
    const hello = await Hello.deployed();
  });
});
```

Comment: truffle deploy a migration contract, this must be excluded somehow when deployen to mainnet. check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-are-truffle-migrations

Comment: that's why I stopped used truffle, when I discovered they store deployment info on the chain. what a horrible design idea

Comment: @Nulik I agree. After posting, I found several other Truffle questions and bug reports  expressing the same bewilderment.  I won't use Truffle again.

Comment: @devdanke the best way to deploy is to use scripts in golang. there is `abigen` command for that, it will create constructor with parameters and also wrapper for all the functions. I am compiling contracts with `solc` to produce combined json format and then just do: `abigen --combined-json artifacts.json --pkg whatever ..etc....`

Comment: @Nulik I'm having success with the **Web3j** Ethereum client.  It can be used in Java, Kotlin, Scala, and Clojure etc.  It can also be used in Android apps.

Comment: @MajdTL  Your comment answered my question :-)   Please post your comment as an _Answer_.  Then I will _Accept_ it.   Thank you.

Comment: @devdanke thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle deploys an extra migration contract. check this question [What are truffle migrations?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-are-truffle-migrations) for more information about it.

This migration contract should be excluded somehow when deployen to mainnet or run the tests.

Answer (score -1):

The first one, with gas usage: 201627, is for the creation of the contract (deploying to the network). The fees after that is to run the contract on the network.

Comment: No. The second transaction isn't to "run" the contract.  Instead, (I learned from @Majd TL) the second transaction posts meta data about my contract to a Truffle _migration history_ contract.  As you can see in my test code above,  after deployment, there is no other interaction with my contract.